Meaning of fall asleep in this context
What does "fall asleep" mean in a football (soccer) context?

Poland fell asleep a little bit there.
Tijjani Reijnders just comes in to that position but he just can't steer it on target. Lovely move though, just pulls it back in front of the defence.


You can tell the text is slightly "suspect" from the fact that it uses the word just three times in two consecutive sentences.

@FumbleFingers -BBC live reporting - remember 'Colemanballs'? I like some of Murray Walker: "There is nothing wrong with the car, apart from that it is on fire", "That car is totally unique, apart from the car behind it, which is identical", and "The gap between them is now nine-tenths of a second; that's less than a second!".

It's just metaphor or hyperbole for not paying good attention. See the fairly recent informal usage "don't sleep on [this opportunity]," meaning don't overlook or miss out.

It is not specific to football/soccer, by the way.

@MichaelHarvey: Indeed. "Questionable" usages by "shoot from the lip" sports commentators account for a quite a lot of questions from learners asking Is this usage correct? I suppose at least part of the reason is that speakers of all languages might be interested in watching sporting contests (with associated commentary). Speech is secondary to activity (the actual gameplay) in such contexts, so native speakers often don't even notice a "Colemanballs" howler until it's pointed out. But for some sports-minded learners, such commentary may be their primary exposure to English!

@FumbleFingers So what does "fall asleep" exactly mean in the sentence?

It's a bit loose, because it wasn't exactly the action of "falling asleep" that caused the problem. Well, I assume Reijnders was playing against Poland, so it was more of a "near miss" than an actual failure. But the scare for Poland came about because metaphorically they were "asleep on the job" Synonyms off-guard
unprepared
unready
napping
unawares
asleep
daydreaming
derelict
inattentive
negligent
unalert
unguarded
unsuspecting
unvigilant
unwatchful
asleep at the switch
flat-footed...

It means to stop paying attention, especially at a crucial moment. It might be related to the expression "fell asleep at the wheel", which means falling asleep while driving.

"fell asleep" means to not notice or otherwise pay attention. An exaggeration. It is AS IF the person was asleep -- with their eyes closed -- when the event occurred.
Often used in sports.  Usually used when a defender completely misses a play AS IF the defender was asleep. Clearly the defender was not actually asleep.  A shorter way of saying "How did the defender miss that play.  Were they asleep?".
